# How to get Xamarin EAAccessoryManager DidConnectNotification to work

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use EAAccessoryManager/Xamarin.Forms to detect when legacy Bluetooth devices connect/disconnect

I am using the following code...
AppDelegate.cs:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{

    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(EAAccessoryManager.DidConnectNotification, EADidConnect);  
    EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.RegisterForLocalNotifications();
```

This never gets called:

```
void EADidConnect(NSNotification notification)
{
    EAAccessory connectedAccessory = (EAAccessory)notification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey((NSString)"EAAccessoryKey");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ConnectedPeripheral");
```

I am using XCode 10.1, iOS 12.1, VS 2017 for Mac 7.7.2

I am using an old Samsung Headset for testing paired to an actual iPhone 6S+.

When the Headset is powered and Connects, I expect EADidConnect to fire.

Comment: Please add more details to this